# Jersey with Appengine Standard and CloudEndpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Our appengine application consists of several microservices deployed in a mix of standard and flex environments. Since we are using both flex and standard we chose jerse to implement our backend services as endpoint framework does not work with flex. We are not able to make this combination of Jersey + Appengine Standard + Endpoint work. When we deploy the swagger using gcloud cloud manager, it does not link with the backend services.

I could not find any  documentation regarding how to integrate App engine standard and endpoint without using endpoint framework annotations.

Has anybody implemented the rest service backends using the combination
Jersey + App engine Standard + Cloud Endpoints. Is it possible to integrate Cloud endpoints and appengine standard without using endpoint framework annotations.

Pls note : We have tested Jersey + Flex + Endpoints and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested or documented, so you are playing in a new area. It should work, and I'm happy to try and help you debug it. To use Endpoints on Standard with Flex, you have to do this:

1. Including this dependency:

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
       <artifactId>endpoints-management-control-appengine-all</artifactId>
       <version>${endpoints.management.version}</version>
   </dependency>`
2. Add this configuration to your `web.xml`, then add a `filter-mapping` to go in front of jersey:

   `<filter>
       <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
           <param-value>${endpoints.project.id}</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
           <param-value>echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </filter>`
3. Upload your OpenAPI specification using `gcloud service-management deploy`.
4. In `appengine-web.xml`, add an environment variable definition:

   `<env-variables>
       <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="echo-api.endpoints.${endpoints.project.id}.cloud.goog" />
   </env-variables>`